What is the intuitive reason the Cauchy family doesn't have an MLR?
Consider the probability density function $\frac{1}{\pi(1 + (x - \theta)^2)}$, for $\theta_1<\theta_2$ (this is the Cauchy density function with scale one), the likelihood ratio $\frac{\bigg(\pi(1 + (x - \theta_2)^2)\bigg)^{-1}}{\bigg(\pi(1 + (x - \theta_1)^2)\bigg)^{-1}}$ is not monotone as a function of $x$. By contrast, the family $N(\theta,1^2)$ does have a monotone likelihood ratio. What is the intuitive explanation for this? Is it all about fat tails?

Essentially yes if your comparison is about two distributions which only differ in location: if the tails are heavier than an exponential distribution then you can see this.  Try the likelihood ratio of two Laplace distributions with the same scale but different locations where, except between the two locations, the likelihood ratio is flat.
